# PHP Mailer ou postfix redirecionando para o gmail?

Tags: php, ubuntu, postfix

**Tenho um servidor Ubuntu(LAMP) e preciso enviar emails via PHP, porém utilizando minha conta no gmail, não quero ter um servidor de e-mail próprio. Preciso definir uma das duas formas abaixo para fazer isso:**

1- Instalar o postfix para fazer o redirecionar para minha conta do gmail e utilizar a função nativa *mail()* do PHP.

2- Utilizar alguma biblioteca em PHP como *PHPMailer* para enviar email utilizando minha conta gmail.

**Dúvida:**

Qual opção um profissional experiente utilizaria? Porque?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com certeza a 2a opção. A função mail() te obriga a lembrar de configurar o SO corretamente. Isso, em alguns casos, principalmente em hospedagem compartilhada, não é possível fazer.

Além do mais, a interface de uso dessas bibliotecas de envio é muito mais intuitiva e amigável em comparação com a função mail().

Existem outras também outras funcionalidades nas bibliotecas que não estão disponíveis ao utilizar a mail(). A biblioteca Swiftmailer, por exemplo, tem a opção de configurar o envio assíncrono das mensagens.